# Combine DRF router with django urlpattern

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I combine together django urlpatterns with DRF router using `app_name = 'scrumboard'`? I tried all ways that are in [DRF documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) explaned but still can't resolve this problem. So far I have following urls.py file:

```
#scrumboard/urls.py

from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from .api import ListViewSet, CardViewSet
from django.urls import re_path, path, include
from . import views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'lists', ListViewSet)
router.register(r'cards', CardViewSet)

app_name = 'scrumboard'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    re_path(r'^api/', include((router.urls))),
]
```

This is my project urls.py:

```
#project/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path, re_path
#Add URL maps to redirect the test URL to our application
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
# Use static() to add url mapping to serve static files during development (only)
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('test/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/catalog/', permanent=True)),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
    path('scrumboard/', include('scrumboard.urls'))
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

In my template I will have an opportunity to define dynamic url like so:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'scrumboard:index' %}">Scrumboard</a></li>
```

which will take me to my Scrumboard app.

With this code above when I go to this url localhost:8000/scrumboard/ I get an Error

[image]

**UPDATE**

When I go to localhost:8000/scrumboard/api it works well

[image]

**UPDATE**

Full Traceback http://dpaste.com/07QR05W

**UPDATE**

Added project urls.py code

Comment: Is `/scrumboard/` supposed to fire the `index` view?

Comment: Did you try to put a router routes before regular view path, with empty urlpath `re_path(r'^', include((router.urls))),` ?

Comment: Yes. I have defined index function that render template under scrumboard/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wanted to delete this question, but I thought maybe someone else would come up against this and decided to describe what the problem really was.

Because of my insufficient experience, I was looking for a problem in the wrong place.

By following the link on the home page template:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'scrumboard:index' %}">Scrumboard</a></li>
```

---

```
#scrumboard/urls.py

from django.urls import re_path, path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'scrumboard'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
]
```

we ran a function defined in view.py that takes this request and renders template under `scrumboard/index.html`

```
#scrumboard/views.py

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'scrumboard/index.html', {})
```

And here flies the error.

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /scrumboard/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'lists' not found. 'lists' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I used django [Reversing namespaced URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls) since I have several applications and every application has his own index.html template. I had to guess that the problem lies somewhere in this template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}


{% block title %}
    <title>Scrumboard</title>
{% endblock %}
{% block extracss %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'scrumboard/css/main.css' %}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
        <a href="{% url 'scrumboard:lists' %}" target="_blank" class="top-menu">Lists</a><br>
        <a href="{% url 'scrumboard:cards' %}" target="_blank" class="top-menu">Cards</a>
        <hr>
          <div ng-app="scrumboard.demo">
            {% verbatim %}
            <div ng-controller="ScrumboardController">
              <div ng-repeat="list in data">
                <h3>{{list.name}}</h3>
                <ul>
                  <li ng-repeat="card in list.cards">{{card.title}}</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" ng-model="new_title">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" ng-click="add(list, new_title)">+</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {% endverbatim %}
              <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'scrumboard/js/scrumboard.js' %}"></script>
          </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Seeing these lines, I thought that the problem is probably in this:

```
<a href="{% url 'scrumboard:lists' %}" target="_blank" class="top-menu">Lists</a><br>
<a href="{% url 'scrumboard:cards' %}" target="_blank" class="top-menu">Cards</a>
```

And I decided to just comment them. And after thinking that the problem was solved, I reloaded the page but the error still flew out again.

```
<!-- <a href="{% url 'scrumboard:lists' %}" target="_blank" class="top-menu">Lists</a><br>
<a href="{% url 'scrumboard:cards' %}" target="_blank" class="top-menu">Cards</a> -->
```

But django ignores the usual html comments and tries to read the commented code. And so my mistake did not go away and I started looking for the problem elsewhere.
And because of inexperience I asked an incorrect question. **Just deleting this lines solve my problem.**

Answer (score 0):

How do we expect that `/scrumboard/` matches the first regex? Is there an outer `urls.py` file with an include of the one you mentioned?

In the absence of more information, does this work?

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('^scrumboard/?$', views.index, name="index"),
    re_path(r'^api/', include((router.urls))),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using Django Rest Framework with Default Router in app1. The following way of defining `extra_kwargs` fixed the error.

```
# app1/serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from app1.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'view_name': 'app1:user-detail'},name
        }
```